# Reporting Services Query With Syntax Error

Tags: sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence, default-value

I have this query where I pass values of one parameter to another.

First parameter is named:

```
@OrdersMonth
```

And is visible to the final user and the second one named:

```
@OrdersPrevMonth
```

Is hidden and gets the value from the visible parameter with the following query:

```
="[Orders].[PrevMonth].&["
& switch(
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value, True, "All",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*All*","All",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*January*","January",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*February*","February",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*March*","March",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*April*","April",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*May*","May",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*June*","June",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*July*","July",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*August*","August",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*September*","September",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*October*","October",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*November*","November",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*December*","December")
& switch(
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value, True, "",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*All*","",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*2013*"," 2013",
Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value Like "*2014*"," 2014")
&"]"
```

The first parameter has values like the following:

```
[Orders].[Month].&[All]   
[Orders].[Month].&[January 2014]
[Orders].[Month].&[February 2014]
```

and so on for years 2013 and 2014

So my intentions to the second parameters which dimensions are:

```
[Orders].[PrevMonth].&[]
```

is to get the same final value (January 2014) whenever first changes with the previous query, but my final output is the following:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   The Value expression for the query parameter ‘OrdenesMesFin’ contains an error: The expression referenced a non-existing parameter in the report parameters collection. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Why is this happening?

Comment: is this what you are putting in the parameter default value?

Answer (score 0):

Gee this looks very familiar ... hola!

Your Switch syntax is incorrect in both cases.  Move the `, True, "All"` to the end of the Switch parameter list, then delete the initial `Parameters!OrdersMonth.Value,`